# Android Custom Camera Image Saved in Wrong Orientation

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I am attempting to create a custom camera for an Android application.  I have successfully gotten the camera with my own customer interface to take pictures, and save them.  The SurfaceView preview is displaying in Portrait mode (which is desired) as well.  My problem is that after the pictures are saved, they aren't displayed in the orientation that the camera was in when the picture was taken.  I know there are a few questions very similar to mine on here, but they haven't been able to assist me.  The phone that I am using for testing this (outside of the emulator of course) is an HTC Evo 4G.  Below is my code broken down.  Thank you so much for any help that you can provide!  Please note, I am doing all of this in a single class, and am saving the Image as a File and NOT as a Bitmap.

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<activity android:name=".CameraClass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

**Button Click**

```
btn_takepicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pic_call);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Picture Callback Method**

```
private PictureCallback pic_call= new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] datas, Camera mCamera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); 
            File myDir = new File(root + "/Images/");  
            myDir.mkdirs();
            if (myDir.exists()){

        }

        Random generator = new Random(); 
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname); 
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);  


        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Intent is = new Intent(CameraClass.this, Display.class);
        is.putExtras(basket);

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(datas);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  

        } catch (IOException e) {                
        }
        startActivity(is);
    }

};
```

**Camera Pause/Release Methods**

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() { 
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();   
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;   
        }
    }
```

**Surface Changed Method**

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {

        }
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error starting mCamera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");

        if(mCamera != null) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Surface Created**

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            camParam = mCamera.getParameters();
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            String currentversion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
            Log.d("System out", "currentVersion " + currentversion);
            int currentInt = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            Log.d("System out", "currentVersion " + currentInt);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                if (currentInt != 7) {
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                } else {
                    Log.d("System out", "Portrait " + currentInt);

                    params.setRotation(90);

                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                if (currentInt != 7) {
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                } else {
                    Log.d("System out", "Landscape " + currentInt);
                    params.set("orientation", "landscape");
                    params.set("rotation", 90);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Surface Destroyed Method**

```
@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

**Set Camera Orientation Method**

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraID, android.hardware.Camera mCamera) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraID, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch(rotation){
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees =0;
        break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90;
        break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180;
        break; 
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270;
        break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        }
        else {
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some devices do not rotate the image when saving it, but rather set an EXIF header saying "hey, image viewer! could you, like, rotate this image when you display it? kthxbye".

That's why in [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), I go through the gyrations to rotate those images, as not all image viewers will honor those EXIF headers.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that the way you did, it helped clear up my confusion on what exactly happens!  I'll take a look at the library and see if there is a way for me to integrate it with my project.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are just Awesome !